# AngularJS unit testing error when using clientWidth

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, jqlite

In my code there's a line:

```
var contentWidth = angular.element(document.querySelector('.content'))[0].clientWidth;
```

It works fine when running the app but when unit testing I get error:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'angular.element(document.querySelector('.content'))[0].clientWidth')
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Guessing this is because there is no DOM built when running your unit test. Try building a mock DOM with the elements you need.

Comment: Not really clear on how to do that...

Comment: Did you attach your compiled element to the document? Otherwise, `document.querySelector()` won't be able to find it.

Answer (score 2):

Either attach DOM when running test or mock the document.querySelector and angular.element in case you don't need the same.

Remember to remove mock/spy on angular element after test is completed as it will interfere with the jasmine framework which uses that internally.

Comment: Could you explain HOW to mock it?